# Issue On SlideToggle Open Slides in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function which is suppose to slide down and up the sub menu under some `<li>` elements.

```
<li class="subtop"><a href="#">Sample 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Sample 1 - 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sample 1 - 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>  
.....
<li class="subtop"><a href="#">Sample 6</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
           <li><a href="#">Sample 6 - 1</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Sample 6 - 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and the jquery is like:

```
$(".subtop").click(function(ev){
   ev.stopPropagation();
   $(this).each(function(){
   $(".sub-menu", this).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

the code is sliding the clicked element's sun menue up and down but I am not able to close existing open `sub-menu` when I click on another `subtop` can you please let me know  how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".subtop").click(function(ev){
   ev.stopPropagation();
   $(".sub-menu").slideUp();
   $(this).each(function(){
   $(".sub-menu", this).slideToggle();
  });
});
```